# Why PHPMyAdmin throws an error in my SQL syntax?

Tags: mysql

It's again PHPMyAdmin... I try to run query on two tables - cards and ownerships (which list all players with the cards they own). And I'd like to create a function which will return (if given the name) the total amount of that card on the market. I defined this in the following way:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  get_card_overall_count (_name TEXT)
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA

BEGIN
DECLARE res INT;
SET res = SELECT SUM(`ownerships`.`amount`) 
          FROM `ownerships` JOIN `cards` ON `ownerships`.`card_ID` = `cards`.`ID`
          WHERE `cards`.`name` = _name 
          GROUP BY `name`;
RETURN res;
END//
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SET` syntax wants the right hand side to be a scalar, not a query, but you can convince it to run a scalar subquery:

```
SET res = (SELECT SUM(`ownerships`.`amount`) 
          FROM `ownerships` JOIN `cards` ON `ownerships`.`card_ID` = `cards`.`ID`
          WHERE `cards`.`name` = _name 
          GROUP BY `name`);
```

Comment: Or alternatively say:  `SELECT res := . . . ` and not use `SET` at all.

Comment: Or `sum(...) into res`

Comment: Okay, that works (I mean, not the result I wanted, but no syntax errors, either)